# Can I have the market update an app that was installed from else where?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm writing an app and would like users to be able to download the apk and install it from my website. However, I would like the app to still be able to update through the market, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and tested, applications installed using .apk files, will be recognized from the android market. Some games though like Angry Birds, do not appear on my list of installed applications and unfortunately I can't find out why.

But for what is worth the following link will help you more.

http://androidforums.com/application-development/65282-can-you-keep-your-paid-app-updating-illegally-installed-apk.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it is possible.
You are better off to link them to the market from your website rather than hosting the APK file.

```
market://search?q=pname:your.package.name
```

That will open the market on the users phone. It is safer and easier than plugging in the phone and installing over USB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without apps like Titanium Backup.  Titanium Backup can link apps to their market counter-parts but you cannot do it without an app like that (which requires Root).

Answer (score 0):

As i know - it's not possible.
Even if you'll use the same package names and signing certificates.