# Google play - how can i send my paid application to one device for free?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an application published on google play and it cost aprox 1$. I would like to send it to my friend for free. Is there an easy way? Like link for 1 use or something?

Comment: Do you have the compiled *.apk file ?

Comment: Ofc i do have apk file but when i release new update then the person who has it installed from phone via apk file he won't recive the update and neither can rate my app and stuff... I need to make it work like it should when you buy it from Google play. Is there a way?

Comment: Give him the signed version of your apk which you have put on Google play. He can surely update, rate the app then.

Comment: But how can i make sure that it can be used just on one device? Or just the devices i choose?

Comment: That I doubt you can't. Only giving to specific persons can ensure that

Answer (score 0):

Applications installed using .apk files, will be recognized from the android market. Some games though like Angry Birds, do not appear on my list of installed applications and unfortunately I can't find out why.

**Reference:**

[Can I have the market update an app that was installed from else where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511727/can-i-have-the-market-update-an-app-that-was-installed-from-else-where)